# C# Button with Text and Down Arrow

Tags: c#, winforms, button, text

Is it possible to create a button with WinForms which has the text "Details" and then a down arrow next to it.

It is not vital to my program but I personally think it looks nicer for the user, especially in dialog boxes which expand to show more error details.

Comment: `char.ConvertFromUtf32(8593)` <-- For Upward `char.ConvertFromUtf32(8595)` <-- For DownWard

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The below code will give your Button the word "Details" with an arrow pointing downwards next to it.

```
Button1.Text = "Details " + char.ConvertFromUtf32(8595);
```

Comment: What is the code for a downwards arrow that looks like > turned by 90 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are asking about the contents of the button itself and want to handle the expand/collaspe functionality yourself. You could create a png with the "down arrow" image, and then position the icon right-middle using the image property of button in the designer.

Comment: I want to set the DetailsButton.Text to show the word "Deails" followed by the arrow.